# Can we have multiple submit buttons on the same page in oracle apex?

Tags: ajax, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a page in oracle apex where I have multiple regions and each region has a Submit page button.

Each submit has an ajax callback associated with it.
Will clicking on any one submit, also execute the other ajax callbacks?

In other words, when we click a Submit page button in one region, is it exclusive only to that regions ajax callback or will it execute all ajax callbacks of that page?

Answer (score 0):

Button name determines value of the `REQUEST` attribute. If you look at the process values, you can set the "Editable Region" (which shows which region is associated with this process), as well as the request itself (under the "Server-side condition" properties; see the "When button pressed" and "Type").

So, if you create your own process which does something and set properties described above, each `SUBMIT` button should affect only its own region.

Unless I'm wrong, if there's only one `SUBMIT` button (created with its default settings) on the page, it'll affect all regions.